# How to set learning rate of individual Link/Function in chainer?

Tags: chainer

caffe can do this. Because some layer of neural network need big learning rate, but conv layer need small lr. How to control different layer have different lr in chainer so that optimizer can update according to correspond lr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite `hyperparam` for each parameter of `update_rule`, which specifies the `optimizer`'s update strategy, in the link like below,

`model.l1.W.update_rule.hyperparam.lr = 0.01`

For details, I already answered the same question at

[How to implement separate learning rate or optimizer in different layer in Chainer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656662/how-to-implement-separate-learning-rate-or-optimizer-in-different-layer-in-chain)

By the way, chainer's Function does not have any `parameter` to be updated, thus function does not have `update_rule`.

Comment: I am sorry to trouble you again. When I set model.l1.W.update_rule.hyperparam.lr = 0.01. How to apply "lr decay after each epoch" when setting this individual layer's learning rate?

Comment: You can create your own `extension` function to change these values.
Please also refer https://gist.github.com/corochann/22ae506123805e1ddece529d8db5b692 for example of your customized extension for learning rate control.